# Add CSS to Vue using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to add style to this `<label>` tag on **Vue**.

```
  <div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-5 mx-7">
      <label class="uppercase md:text-sm text-xs text-gray-500 text-light font-semibold mb-1 flex items-center justify-center">Upload Photo</label>
        <div class='flex items-center justify-center w-full'>    
            <label  id="img1" class='flex flex-col border-4 border-dashed w-40 h-32 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:border-purple-300 group'>
                 <div @click="onPrimaryPicSelected" class='flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-7'>
                  <svg class="w-10 h-10 text-purple-400 group-hover:text-purple-600" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 16l4.586-4.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L16 16m-2-2l1.586-1.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L20 14m-6-6h.01M6 20h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"></path></svg>
                  <p class='lowercase text-sm text-gray-400 group-hover:text-purple-600 pt-1 tracking-wider'>Select a photo</p>
                </div>
              <input type='file' class="hidden" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want that when the `onPrimaryPicSelected` function is called to add a CSS styling to the `<label>` tag. How can I do this if it is possible?

Currently the `onPrimaryPIcSelected` just gets the image that was uploaded.

```
 onPrimaryPicSelected(event) {
      this.primaryPhoto = event.target.files[0];
      this.primaryPhotoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    },
```

Comment: Inside your Labeltag you can use Class-Binding or Style Binding. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html. ```:class="selected ? 'new-classes-here'``` .  selected is an new memberVar from type boolean. in your method you can change from default false to true. and the new Classes will aplly to your label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable if true it will apply your style to the label tag.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-5 mx-7">
  <label class="uppercase md:text-sm text-xs text-gray-500 text-light font-semibold mb-1 flex items-center justify-center" :style="selected ? 'your-style-here' : ''">Upload Photo</label>
    <div class='flex items-center justify-center w-full'>    
        <label  id="img1" class='flex flex-col border-4 border-dashed w-40 h-32 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:border-purple-300 group'>
             <div @click="onPrimaryPicSelected" class='flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-7'>
              <svg class="w-10 h-10 text-purple-400 group-hover:text-purple-600" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 16l4.586-4.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L16 16m-2-2l1.586-1.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L20 14m-6-6h.01M6 20h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"></path></svg>
              <p class='lowercase text-sm text-gray-400 group-hover:text-purple-600 pt-1 tracking-wider'>Select a photo</p>
            </div>
          <input type='file' class="hidden" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your function

```
onPrimaryPicSelected(event) {
  this.selected = true;
  this.primaryPhoto = event.target.files[0];
  this.primaryPhotoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
},
```

Comment: that is correct, but a small improvment.  instead :style use :class inside the label tag.

Comment: Hey great solution but i cant seem to use this.primaryPhoto inside the :style.